# need to change a specific cell's color in a table, simple beginner level PHP

Tags: php, html

I had to make a calendar for a school project. I need to change number/day 8 and 9's color to red in the calendar, but I don't know how. Thanks  in advance. Also the text written in Farsi is just sat, sun, mon ...

```
<?php
echo( '<header style="text-align: left; color: black;background-color: yellow"><b>شهریور ۱۳۹۹</b></header>' );
$day = array( "شنبه", "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنج شنبه", "جمعه" );
$table = "<table width='511' height='345' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' dir='rtl' 
style='text-align:center; background-color: antiquewhite'><tr>";

for ( $i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++ ) {
    $table .= "<td><b><u>$day[$i]</u></b></td>";
}

$table .= "</tr><tr>";

for ( $j = 1; $j <= 35; $j++ ) {
    if ( $j <= 31 ) {
        $table .= "<td>$j</td>";
    } else {
        $table .= "<td> </td>";
    }

    if ( ( $j % 7 ) == 0 ) $table .= "</tr><tr>";
}

$table .= "</tr></table>";
echo $table;

echo( '<footer style="text-align: left; color: black;background-color: yellow"><b></b></footer>' )
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you are learning the language and trying to implement a calendar with some conditional and looping logic.

The below code does what you looking for. That is, it will colour the dates 8 and 9 in red by checking the whether the current variable value `$j` in the loop is 8 OR 9.

The Operator `||` is called `LOGICAL OR`, which will return `TRUE` is any of the condition is TRUE. In your case, `8 OR 9` and if it returns true then we paint the `td` with CSS. That's it.

But I need you to care more about your coding if you are sticking with this industry. Below are the things that I used for making your code little bit easier to read and understand.

- Use `PHP` inside `HTML` rather than the opposite. Eg: Use `<u><?= $day[$i] ?></u>` instead of `echo "<u>$day[$i]</u>"`.
- Use Alternative syntaxes for `if`, `for` and more. Using alternative syntax inside HTML will look much cleaner.
- Properly format your code for you and your friends to easily read and understand.

```php
<?php

$day = array( "شنبه", "یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنج شنبه", "جمعه" );

?>

<header style="text-align: left; color: black;background-color: yellow">
    <b>شهریور ۱۳۹۹</b> 
</header>

<table width='511' height='345' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' dir='rtl' style='text-align:center; background-color: antiquewhite'>

    <tr>
        <?php for ( $i=0; $i<=6; $i++ ): ?>
            <td>
                <b>
                    <u><?= $day[$i] ?></u>
                </b>
            </td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <?php for ( $j=1; $j<=35; $j++ ): ?>

            <?php if ( $j<=31 ): ?>

                <?php if ( $j==8 || $j==9 ): ?>

                    <td style="background-color:red;"><?= $j ?></td>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <td><?= $j ?></td>

                <?php endif; ?>



            <?php else: ?>

                <td></td>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( ($j % 7) == 0): ?>

                </tr><tr>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endfor; ?>

    </tr>
</table>

<footer style="text-align: left; color: black;background-color: yellow"><b></b></footer>
```